# Why isn't this jQuery image switcher working?

Tags: jquery

I have a main image, with circular divs below. I would like to change the main image when one of these divs is clicked, with it's containing image. This is proving more challenging than I thought. Sorry if this is 'help vampire-y', but I don't know what else to try.

```
    <div class="span6 slider">
            <img src="img/food-and-drink/taps.jpg" alt="Photograph of beer taps">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <a href="#"><div class="slider-circle"><img src="img/food-and-drink/kegs.jpg" alt="Photograph of kegs"></div></a>
                    <a href="#"><div class="slider-circle"></div></a>
                    <a href="#"><div class="slider-circle"></div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Jquery

```
    var currentSlide = $('.slider img').attr('src');
$('.slider-circle').click(function() {
    $currentSlide = $(this).child().attr('src');
})
```

SOLVED - With Christopher Marshall's solutions. Thank you very much!

```
    $('.slider-circle').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $newSlide = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        $('.slider > img').attr('src', $newSlide);
    });
```

Comment: `currentSlide` != `$currentSlide`

Comment: jQuery object doesn't have `child` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xhc7K/)</kbd>

```
$('.slider-circle').click(function() {
    var $newSlide = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $('.slider > img').attr('src', $newSlide);
})
```

Comment: Surely `attr('src')` just returns a string, and not a reference to the property which can then be changed elsewhere?

Comment: That's a good point, but I believe it should still work. I'll create a fiddle in a sec. (Love muse btw)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want:

```
$('.slider-circle').click(function() {
    $mainSlide = $('.slider > img');//get a reference to the main slide img
    $currentSlide = $(this).find('img');//get a reference to the selected img
    $mainSlide.attr('src', $currentSlide.attr('src'));//set the main img src attribute to match the selected img src attribute
})
```

However, this does assume you only have once element with class `slider`

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand how it's going to work so I'm going to break it down for you.

1. Attach click event to all circle-images

   $('.slider-circle').click(function() {

   });
2. When the div is clicked, retrieve the containing img src value

   $('.slider-circle').click(function() {

   var new_src = $(this).find('img').prop("src");

   });
3. Create a function to switch the main image

   function switchImage(new_src) {

   $('.slider > img').prop("src", new_src);

   }
4. Put it together

Code:

```
$('.slider-circle').click(function() {
  new_src = $(this).find('img').prop("src");
  switchImage(new_src);
});
function switchImage(new_src) {
  $('.slider > img').prop("src", new_src);
}
```

Shortened Code:

```
$('.slider-circle').click(function() {
  $('.slider > img').prop("src", $(this).find('img').prop("src"));
}
```